How to restore the iPhone without downloading the latest version of iOS?
I am trying to unlock my old iPhone using the guide from apple. On step 4 "Restore your iPhone with your Mac or PC" it says

Your computer downloads software for your iPhone and begins the restore process

When clicking restore, it asks me to Restore and Update. I don't want to update the iPhone to the latest version, so I don't want to confirm. There's no information about what will happen after it.
So my question is twofold:

What will happen after I click on Restore and Update?


How to restore the iPhone without downloading the latest version of iOS?


This post suggested that it will not update the phone, but after clicking the Restore button, Apple is forcing me to update the software before proceeding.
I force unplugged the phone but it remembered the choice, and is displaying that the computer is currently downloading software for this phone (even if the process is suspened).


How to restore the iPhone without downloading the latest version of iOS?


Edit: I am on Mac 14.6.1 using Finder and the phone is some version of iOS 15. I cannot check because the phone is iCloud locked.

What version does your old phone run? The exact worlds for erase content and settings changes a bit based on how old it is… also, what specifically is “unlock the phone” my answer might need an edit based on what that means, but the main point is clear you don’t want to click update so I’ll get that part of the answer up now.

@bmike The phone is iCloud locked. I am trying to unlock it by entering my Apple ID

Activation lock doesn’t care if you restore the device or not, it’s still locked. You need this - https://support.apple.com/en-us/108934

Do you have control of the locking account and see the device in step 3 above?

What you want is to erase all content and settings which returns the device to the setup assist and with the current firmware and software. Some people call this a factory reset.
You are correct that if you restore and update, that will update the OS and then offer to restore data from the backup of the current version.
If your phone only boots to recovery, we may need more details to assist or understand why updating the OS would be problematic.

But he doesn't want the current version.  I am wondering: if all internet access is disabled, will a restore leave the firmare and O.S. as-is?

The OP edited some good details. I wonder if you already have a signed version of iOS on Apple Configurator or iTunes or macOS Finder cached if your trick to restore is allowed to run without internet. I’m certain the device will eventually need a connection to activate the install.

Find a website that holds the iOS version that you wish. Then, download the IPA and follow tutorials on YouTube.
